# Is any android library help to develop a photo editor app?

Tags: android, image, editor, photo, android-library

I want to make a photo editor for android app.
After take a photo, it will showed on canvas and user can draw or add text or put other image into the canvas, than save it.

Is there any Android library can help me to develop it easier? free or not free both OK.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

[aviary](https://developers.aviary.com/)

[jjil](https://code.google.com/p/jjil/)

[android media effect](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/effect/package-summary.html)

Comment: I tried the aviary sdk, it is really good. But I want to allow user to add their own image to be stickers. I asked aviary.com for this, but they have not reply me.